# Can I pass in a frozen time as a setting into postgresql and not have clock drift?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to freeze time on a connection level across multiple transactions. Is there a conventional way of achieving this similar to

```
SET search_path = 'foo';
```

Rather than me passing in the time and binding it on each statement myself? Ideally I would want to be able to use `NOW()` and write conventional SQL, but freeze that time across multiple transactions.

The reason for this is because I want to avoid clock drift on a single web request.

Comment: Inside a single transaction this is possible, but not across multiple transactions unless you use your own implementation of `now()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, I definitely wouldn't want everything that happens across a web request to be wrapped in a single transaction just to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse a placeholder variable:

```
SET request.time = '2019-11-21 09:00:00';
```

Then you can use `current_setting('request.time')` in your queries to retrieve the string.